# angularjs convert 0 to 1 in number (html5) field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

its an odd behavior. m using input field field where type is number

and if i enter 1230 model value remains -> 1230

but as i type 01 its becomes -> 1

where as i can see 01 in input value . so this something to do with angular js

i need 00 in model because its user phone number and number type is to stop user from entering text

any help will be appreciated

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D

test can be run at angular site

Comment: Sounds like you should be using strings for this. I'm guessing that you're assinging the input to a numeric type, hence the preceeding 0 is being dropped. Can you post your code?

Comment: Why use input[type='number'] if you're dealing with telephone numbers, i suggest you a combination with input[type='text'] and a regex validator .

Comment: well changing to text is last resort but before doing it i wana try if someone has fixed it already

Comment: @phil about code . i have provided link in question . just try 01 there and u will see model value will be 1

Comment: @Salman - as Akram said change the input type from number to text. `<input type="number" ...` to `<input type="text"... `. Also remove max and min attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The type `number` allows you to enter `+-,.`. So you cannot achieve your goal of preventing the user from entering "invalid" numbers in the first place.

It's also not very user friendly, as telephone numbers are often formatted using spaces and braces. A user can no longer copy and paste such values into the input field. Digits in phone numbers can also be represented by letters btw. `123-HELLO` is equal to `12343556`.

Please note that there's also an input type `tel`. It's not particularly useful but semantically more appropriate.

If you only want to save and display the value then use the input as is. It doesn't make much sense to force a user to adhere to your preferred pattern. Adding `pattern` or `ngPattern` allows you to use regular expressions to limit the possible characters. If you need the plain number then strip all non-numeric characters - and possibly convert roman letters to numbers - before usage.